# How to center my <h3> text using css?

Tags: html, css, text, center

I have the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/z2rTw/1/)

The `HTML` is created by `javascript`. I can add/change the styles to the `div's` if needed but I cannot change the order of the HTML code.

I know I can use:

```
text-align: center;
```

But there is a catch :) The `div` containing the 4 images is put in the `HTML` code before the `<h3>` is. Since I cannot edit the `HTML` order I figured to lower the `DIV` with the images using `margin-top: 70px;` The problem is that this has an effect on the text in the `<h3>` which isn't `centered` anymore.

How to solve this? (pref with css3)

It's okay if the values of the `DIV's` in the `HTML` need to be changed in order to fix it
(I can change them)

Thanks a lot

The HTML code:

```
<div class="solitaireprefs" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 80%; height: 80%; z-index: 100;">
<form method="get" action="">
    <div style="float: right; margin-top: 70px; display: table; vertical-align: bottom;">
        <div><img src="cardsets/test/spades1.svg" alt="Ace spades" align="bottom" style="vertical-align: bottom; width: 119px; height: 166px;"><img src="cardsets/test/clubs7.svg" alt="7 clubs" align="bottom" style="vertical-align: bottom; width: 119px; height: 166px;"></div>
        <div><img src="cardsets/test/hearts12.svg" alt="Queen hearts" align="bottom" style="vertical-align: bottom; width: 119px; height: 166px;"><img src="cardsets/test/backred.svg" alt="Card" align="bottom" style="vertical-align: bottom; width: 119px; height: 166px;"></div>
    </div>
    <h3>Options</h3>
    <h4>Images for size 119</h4>
</form>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
div.solitaireprefs {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 7px; 
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

div.solitaireprefs form {
    padding: 0 15px;
}

div.solitaireprefs h3 {
    background: #e9e9e9;
    margin: 0 -15px;
    padding: .7em 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0 0 ; 
}
```

Comment: Post your code in your question.

Comment: @j08691 What's wrong with the fiddle?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP - If jsFiddle is not acessible then this question, without the code, loses its value. Code in the question first, then a fiddle.

Comment: @j08691 I don't think this question will be useful to others past the time in which that link could die, but okay - fair enough, I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `float:right;` and `margin:top` on the element that contains the images, position it absolutely.

```
{ position: absolute;
  top: 70px; 
  right: 10px;
}
```

Using absolute positioning takes it out of the flow of the document; which is what is messing up the centering on your `h3`.

Comment: Glad it works for you! It's a hacky solution for a hacky situation; as others have said, using more correct markup would be better overall.

Answer (score 4):

The real answer to the question is to figure out how you can arrange the dom elements correctly. Semantics is more important than you think. But since you are already kinda hacking the visuals, the quickest and dirtiest hack is to fix your padding:

```
padding: .7em 45%;
```

on the div.solitairprefs h3
Tweak the percentage to get the middle, but the missing 10% of the sum of left and right padding on the h3 is the space between where the options text appears (so tweak accordingly).
And since you're already manually centering, you can go ahead and get rid of the

`text-align: center;`

Comment: If you go with KatieK's response, be sure to also set the text-align to center in the h3 tag. Additionally, be careful when using absolute, as katie said, it will take it out of the flow of the document, so if you wanted it to appear inside that div, you will have to manually set the size of the div to make it "appear" that those images are inside the div.

Comment: I agree on the re-arrange the DOM's, but the script is very big and to be honest my JS skills aren't that good. So for now I'll hack it and later on rearrange it (hopefully)